# Generate a random 32-bit number to store in a 64-bit register

Tags: x86, x86-64, cpu-registers, 32-bit, rdrand

I want to generate a random 32-bit number. I am using `rdrand` for this. However, I am having some problems. Since the number can be no more than 32 bits large, I am doing `rdrand eax`. Here is where the problem arises:

- I need to be able to refer to this 32-bit number in a 64-bit register since the rest of my codebase uses 64-bit registers. I figured that I could clear `rax` with a `xor` to itself, and then only load half of it with `rdrand eax`. Then I could look at `rax`, have one half be at most a 32-bit number, and the other half be cleared.
- When I compare `rax` with the maximum 32-bit number size, *2147483647*, I get very inconsistent results. Half of the time, the exit code is 1, meaning that the number in `rax` is, in fact, smaller than 32-bits. But the other half of the time I get 0. It's almost like the result in `eax` is not always less than or equal to *2147483647*, which is unexpected given what [this](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdrand) documentation says.

Does anyone know what is going wrong in my thought process? I am very curious to know. (Note: I'm assembling with Clang on macOS.)

```
    .global _main
    .text

# how to generate a 32-bit random number that is in rax?
_main:
    xor rax, rax  # clear the top half of the eax-rax register pair
    rdrand eax  # a 32-bit number in rax

    cmp rax, 2147483647
    jle smaller_than_32  # rax <= MAX_32_BIT
    xor rdi, rdi
    jmp end
    smaller_than_32:
        mov rdi, 1
    end:
        mov rax, 0x2000001
        syscall
```

Comment: `xor rax, rax` is pointless.  `rdrand eax` implicitly zero-extends into RAX.  [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137).  That's why [`xor edi,edi` works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) to zero the full register.  Also you could `xor edi,edi` / `cmp eax, 2147483647` / `setg dil` instead of branching.  Or just `test eax,eax` / `setns` to check the MSB via the sign flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2147483647`, or equivalently, `0x7FFFFFFF`, is the maximum *signed* 32-bit number. `rdrand eax` can put any value from `0x00000000` to `0xFFFFFFFF` in `eax`. You have a few choices for how to handle this:

1. Compare it with `4294967295`, or equivalently `0xFFFFFFFF`, the maximum *unsigned* 32-bit number, instead.
2. Do `cmp eax, 2147483647` instead of `cmp rax, 2147483647`. Since `jle` operates on the result of comparing signed integers, this will cause what you're now seeing as `2147483648` through `4294967295` to instead be interpreted as `-2147483648` through `-1`.
3. Instead of having the upper 32 bits of `rax` always be zero, have them match the sign bit of `eax` instead (this is known as *sign-extending*). You can do this by doing `movsx rax, eax` right after `rdrand eax`. This will cause `rax` to hold a value between `-2147483648` and `2147483647` instead of between `0` and `4294967295`.

Any of those changes will result in your conditional jump always being taken, as you expect. If you want `rax` to end up being between `0` and `4294967295`, then choose option 1 or 2. If you want `rax` to end up being between `-2147483648` and `2147483647`, then choose option 3.

Comment: Of course, once you understand that you're getting a 32-bit number, not a 31-bit number, you don't need to cmp/jle or `test eax,eax` / `jns` at all.  Since you don't actually need to range-check `rdrand`'s output, option 1 and 2 are equivalent (use it raw, no movsx).  I guess you could say that it's a matter of whether the rest of your program treats it as a 32-bit / 64-bit unsigned, or a 32-bit signed number.